# Is there a way to make images scrolling in viewPager of landscape mode?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'am setting up a kind of books in android studio witch is reading sort of images, and want to the images in the landscape mode to be scrolling from Up to Down

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imagesURLs[position])
            .fit()
            //.//centerInside()//centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    container.addView(imageView);
    click(position, imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

and that is the XML code

```
<com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layoutDirection="locale" />
```

so here is the screenshot of what i got as scaling in all edges 
the Size of Image(1600x1094px)
[Take a look at the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGQK.png)